# How effective is Moore Penrose for solving regression problems with overdetermined system of equations?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, dimensionality-reduction, linear-algebra, partial-least-squares

For regression problems with #Predictors > #observations, I recently read about Moore Penrose (pseudo inverse method) which solves the problem of non invertible matrix in OLS for regression problems.

[image]

How well does this 'generally' perform as compared to some of the other alternatives such as Ridge/Lasso, Partial least squares, Principle component regression?

Also, while datasets with predictors > observations, is there a method among the above listed that always performs better than the rest (purely in terms of prediction accuracy)?